# How can I call an instance on a former instance from the same class?

Tags: python, inheritance, instance

I apologize in advance if there is an obvious solution to this question or it is a duplicate.

I have a class as follows:

```
class Kernel(object):
    """ creates kernels with the necessary input data """
    def __init__(self, Amplitude, random = None):
        self.Amplitude = Amplitude
        self.random = random
        if random != None:
            self.dims = list(random.shape)

    def Gaussian(self, X, Y, sigmaX, sigmaY, muX=0.0, muY=0.0):
        """ return a 2 dimensional Gaussian kernel """
        kernel = np.zeros([X, Y])
        theta = [self.Amplitude, muX, muY, sigmaX, sigmaY]
        for i in range(X):
            for j in range(Y):
                kernel[i][j] = integrate.dblquad(lambda x, y: G2(x + float(i) - (X-1.0)/2.0, \
                                                 y + float(j) - (Y-1.0)/2.0, theta), \
                                                 -0.5, 0.5, lambda y: -0.5, lambda y: 0.5)[0]
        return kernel
```

It just basically creates a bunch of convolution kernels (I've only included the first).

I want to add an instance (method?) to this class so that I can use something like

```
conv = Kernel(1.5)
conv.Gaussian(9, 9, 2, 2).kershow()
```

and have the array pop up using Matplotlib. I know how to write this instance and plot it with Matplotlib, but I don't know how to write this class so that for each method I would like to have this additional ability (i.e. `.kershow()`), I may call it in this manner.

I *think* I could use decorators ? But I've never used them before. How can I do this?

Comment: It looks like the `Gaussian` function's `kernel` object is a numpy array, which that function returns. Do numpy arrays have a `kershow` method? If not, you would have to either add it to the numpy source (I assume it's open-source) or create a function in your class that accepts such an array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the thing you're looking for is function or [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Strings are a really good example of this in Python. Because a string is immutable, each string method returns a new string. So you can call string methods on the return values, rather than storing the intermediate value. For example:

```
lower = '       THIS IS MY NAME: WAYNE      '.lower()
without_left_padding = lower.lstrip()
without_right_padding = without_left_padding.rstrip()
title_cased = without_right_padding.title()
```

Instead you could write:

```
title_cased = '       THIS IS MY NAME: WAYNE      '.lower().lstrip().rstrip().title()
```

<sup><sub>Of course really you'd just do `.strip().title()`, but this is an example.</sub></sup>

So if you want a `.kernshow()` option, then you'll need to include that method on whatever you return. In your case, numpy arrays don't have a `.kernshow` method, so you'll need to return something that does.

Your options are mostly:

- A subclass of numpy arrays
- A class that wraps the numpy array

I'm not sure what is involved with subclassing the numpy array, so I'll stick with the latter as an example. Either you can use the kernel class, or create a second class.

Alex provided an example of using your kernel class, but alternatively you could have another class like this:

```
class KernelPlotter(object):
    def __init__(self, kernel):
        self.kernel = kernel

    def kernshow(self):
        # do the plotting here
```

Then you would pretty much follow your existing code, but rather than `return kernel` you would do `return KernelPlotter(kernel)`.

Which option you choose really depends on what makes sense for your particular problem domain.

---

There's another sister to function chaining called a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#Python) that's basically function chaining but with the goal of making the interface read like English. For example you might have something like:

```
Kernel(with_amplitude=1.5).create_gaussian(with_x=9, and_y=9, and_sigma_x=2, and_sigma_y=2).show_plot()
```

Though obviously there can be [some problems](https://ocramius.github.io/blog/fluent-interfaces-are-evil/) when writing your code this way.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```
class Kernel(object):

    def __init__ ...

    def Gaussian(...):
        self.kernel = ...
        ...
        return self  # not kernel

    def kershow(self):
        do_stuff_with(self.kernel)
```

Basically the `Gaussian` method doesn't return a numpy array, it just stores it in the `Kernel` object to be used elsewhere in the class. In particular `kershow` can now use it. The `return self` is optional but allows the kind of interface you wanted where you write

```
conv.Gaussian(9, 9, 2, 2).kershow()
```

instead of

```
conv.Gaussian(9, 9, 2, 2)
conv.kershow()
```